# react native view not updating

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to show a view based on some condition but the view does not appear at all. Here is my code -

```
showView = async () => {
        let isConditionFulfilled = await checkCondition();
        console.log('isConditionFulfilled' + isConditionFulfilled)
        return isConditionFulfilled;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                {this.showView() ? null : <Text>Welcome</Text>}
            </ View>
        );
    }
```

The problem is the view does not update at all with 'Welcome' when it is false. Although my console log gives me false.
What is the problem exactly?

Comment: Call the async function inside the render method for check the Boolean condition, it will check only defined or not. Since method is defined it will always return `true`. For async operation introduce state variable and update the state variable inside the async function, based on state variable it will re-render the component

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state={
        isConditionFulfilled : false
    }
}

componentDidMount(){
    this.showView()
}

showView = async () => {
    await this.setState({isConditionFulfilled : checkCondition()})
}

render() {
    return (
        <View>
            {this.state.isConditionFulfilled ? <Text>Welcome</Text>: null}
        </ View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`showView` function is an async function, so it returns a promise. To use it properly you handle this promise situation. For example:

```
class App extends React.Component {

    showView = async () => {
    let isConditionFulfilled = await checkCondition();
    console.log('isConditionFulfilled', isConditionFulfilled)
    return isConditionFulfilled;
  }

  render() {
    let isConditionFulfilled;
    this.showView().then( res => {
      if (res) { isConditionFulfilled = true; }
      isConditionFulfilled = false;
    } )
    return (
      <div>
      {
          isConditionFulfilled ? <p>Foo</p> : null
      }
      </ div>
    );
  }
}
```

But, this is not a nice way of handling a situation like that. Use a lifecycle method to fetch your result, then set this value to your state. In your render method, check this state value and conditionally render your items. This is why we have state and lifecycle methods.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isConditionFulfilled: false,
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.showView().then( res => this.setState({
      isConditionFulfilled: res,
    }))
  }

  showView = async () => {
    let isConditionFulfilled = await checkCondition();
    console.log('isConditionFulfilled', isConditionFulfilled)
    return isConditionFulfilled;
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
      {
        this.state.isConditionFulfilled ? <p>Foo</p> : null  
      }
      </ div>
    );
  }
}
```